# How to define a column with underline in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to differentiate the header and data in pandas dataframe by keeping column names with underline.
Or other way to achieve this is to draw a line between column-name and rows in pandas dataframe as shown below. I am running python code with 3.9.2 version in visual studio.

Please advise if this can be done within pandas dataframe.

Input: Read through excel sheet.

```
DF1 = pandas.read_excel("Input.xlsx",sheet_name=0)

OFFICE NO  DAY HOURS    DAY RATES
 101        8            60
 102        8            80
```

Output: DF2 requires columns with underscore or line to separate from data.

```
 OFFICE NO  DAY HOURS    DAY RATES
 --------------------------------- 
 101        8            60
 102        8            80
```

Eventually, this dataframe DF2 will be written into text file.

```
df2.to_string('./output.txt', index=False)
```

Kindly provide inputs on how to draw a line after a column or create column with underscore using pandas dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `to_markdown`:

```
df.to_markdown('./output.txt', index=False, tablefmt='simple')
!type output.txt # On windows machine
```

Output:

```
  OFFICE NO    DAY HOURS    DAY RATES
-----------  -----------  -----------
        101            8           60
        102            8           80
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott Boston.  It worked after the installation of  package : tabulate with your provided code.

Comment: I have done that @ Scott Boston, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Scott Boston, your provided solution helped a lot. Thanks.

I have explored few more uses with "markdown". Putting here as it could be useful for others.

Comment: (1) df1 = df.to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt= 'simple') This creates a string with underline to header.
It can be replaced with "lines" using replace command. df1 = df1.replace('-','_')
Finally, the header with lines will be written into text file outfile.write(df1).

Comment: (2) other use case : if dataframe has any float number fields that requires to be populated in text with 2 digit decimal format. This is also achievable with markdown 
df1 = df.to_markdown(index=False, floatfmt= ".2f", tablefmt= 'simple')